# incorrect checksum for freed object related to passing multi-dimensional vector into a static function in c++

Tags: c++, vector, malloc, checksum

I have been working on a very extensive program over the last few months for the research I have been conducting. Unfortunately I cannot go into this research, or most of the program for various reasons, but I have run into a problem that I cannot seem to understand so I've kind of run out of options than to try stack overflow.

The part of the program I can show takes some data that is stored in 2-D or 3-D vectors, and passes them into a Kernel Ridge Regression function that I am building. Within this function I split the various sets of data into training and test sets for cross validation. After finding the kernel and performing regularization I then pass the modified kernel, along with the test data, into a Guass-Jordan Elimination function I have built, to solve for x in Ax = b. The issue I'm having is that, upon completion of this function the program crashes with this error:

agnigen(28820,0x7fff7512b000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9fa2a063f8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

Now I have narrowed this error down using valgrind to the x vector, which gets passed as a reference to the Gauss-Jordan elimination function. However, I'm at a complete loss as to why this error is occurring and I would appreciate any help you can give me. Below will be the code that I can show (as it does not give away anything that is technically classified), but if you need more I will do my best to provide it. Thank you for your help.

This is where the KRR function gets called: a file called Run

```
LearningAlgorithms::KRR(dataStorage,trainingFP,trainingForces,prediction);
```

This is the KRR function:

```
  void LearningAlgorithms::KRR(DataStorage *dS, vector<vector<double> > trainingPoints, vector<vector<double> > trainingForces, vector<double> &prediction)
{
   //variable declarations for KRR

int cvFolds = atoi(dS->getCV()[1].c_str());

int trainPartitionSize = (int) trainingPoints.size() / cvFolds;

double distance = 0.0;

vector<double> lambdas,sigmas,errors;

vector<vector<double> > alphas,trainingSet, testSet, randomizedTrainingPoints,trainingSetForces, testSetForces, randomizedTrainingForces, kernelMatrix;

vector<vector<vector<double > > > cvAlphas;

prediction.resize(trainingPoints.size());
trainingSet.resize(trainPartitionSize);
testSet.resize(trainingPoints.size() - trainPartitionSize);
trainingSetForces.resize(trainPartitionSize);
testSetForces.resize(trainingPoints.size() - trainPartitionSize);

for(int i = 0; i < trainingSet.size(); i++)
    trainingSet[i].resize(trainingPoints[0].size());

for(int i = 0; i < testSet.size(); i++)
    testSet[i].resize(trainingPoints[0].size());

for(int i = 0; i < trainingSetForces.size(); i++)
    trainingSetForces[i].resize(1);

for(int i = 0; i < testSetForces.size(); i++)
    testSetForces[i].resize(1);

//set sizes of hyper-parameter vectors based on whether cross validation was chosen or not
if(dS->getCV()[0] == "T" || dS->getCV()[0] == "t")
{
    cout<<"Training model using "<<cvFolds<<"-fold Kernel Ridge Regression"<<endl;

    lambdas.resize(cvFolds);
    sigmas.resize(cvFolds);
    errors.resize(cvFolds);
    cvAlphas.resize(cvFolds);

    for(int i = 0; i < lambdas.size(); i++)
    {
        lambdas[i] = Math::randomDouble(dS->getLambdaRange()[0],dS->getLambdaRange()[1]);
        sigmas[i] = Math::randomDouble(dS->getSigmaRange()[0],dS->getSigmaRange()[1]);
    }
}
else
{
    cout<<"Training model using Kernel Ridge Regression without cross validation"<<endl;

    lambdas.resize(1);
    sigmas.resize(1);
    errors.resize(1);
    cvAlphas.resize(1);

    lambdas[0] = Math::randomDouble(dS->getLambdaRange()[0],dS->getLambdaRange()[1]);
    sigmas[0] = Math::randomDouble(dS->getSigmaRange()[0],dS->getSigmaRange()[1]);
}

//randomizes training points to diversify partitions during cross validation
Utilities::coordinatedRandomization2Darray(trainingPoints, randomizedTrainingPoints,trainingForces,randomizedTrainingForces);

//optimize lambda and sigma based on range provided
for(int lambda = 0; lambda < lambdas.size(); lambda++)
{
    for(int sigma = 0; sigma < sigmas.size(); sigma++)
    {
        for(int fold = 0; fold < cvFolds; fold++)
        {
            int trainingIndex = 0;
            int testIndex = 0;
            int sum = 0;

            //partitions training points into training and test sets based on cross validation
            for(int training = 0; training < randomizedTrainingPoints.size(); training++)
            {
                sum = 0;

                if(training >= trainPartitionSize * fold && training < trainPartitionSize * (fold + 1))
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < randomizedTrainingPoints[0].size(); i++)
                        trainingSet[trainingIndex][i] = randomizedTrainingPoints[training][i];

                    for(int i = 0; i < randomizedTrainingForces[0].size(); i++)
                        sum += randomizedTrainingForces[training][i];

                    trainingSetForces[trainingIndex][0] = sum;

                    trainingIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < randomizedTrainingPoints[0].size(); i++)
                        testSet[testIndex][i] = randomizedTrainingPoints[training][i];

                    for(int i = 0; i < randomizedTrainingForces[0].size(); i++)
                        sum += randomizedTrainingForces[training][i];

                    testSetForces[trainingIndex][0] = sum;

                    testIndex++;
                }           
            }

            //clears the kernel matrix and resizes based on test set size

            kernelMatrix.clear();
            kernelMatrix.resize(testSet.size());

            for(int km = 0; km < kernelMatrix.size(); km++)
                kernelMatrix[km].resize(testSet.size());

            //determines the kernel for a given test set
            for(int testIndex = 0; testIndex < testSet.size(); testIndex++)
            {
                for(int ntrain = 0; ntrain < testSet.size(); ntrain++)
                {
                    distance = 0.0;

                    for(int i = 0; i < testSet[testIndex].size(); i++)
                        distance += pow(testSet[testIndex][i] - testSet[ntrain][i],2);

                    kernelMatrix[testIndex][ntrain] = ... (sorry, can't show this)
                }
            }

            //performs a lambda regularization on the kernel matrix to account for noise in the data
            Math::regularization(kernelMatrix, lambdas[lambda]);


            //solves linear system of equations to get our parameterization term (b) and our alpha vectors
            //A = kernel matrix, x = alpha , b = forces : Ax = b
            Math::gaussJordanElimination(kernelMatrix,alphas, testSetForces);

        }
    }
}
```

This is the Gauss-Jordan Elimination function:

```
    void Math::gaussJordanElimination(vector< vector< double > > A, vector<vector<double > > &x, vector< vector< double > > b)
{
  int i, icolumn, irow, j, k, l, ll;

double ainvabs, dum, pivinv;

int n = A.size();
int m = A[0].size();

vector< int> indxc, indxr, ipivot;

vector< vector< double > > Ainv;

indxc.resize(n);
indxr.resize(n);
ipivot.resize(n);

x.resize(b.size());

//puts values from b into x, and A into A inverse
for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
{
    x[i].resize(b[i].size());

    for(int j = 0; j < x[i].size(); j++)
        x[i][j] = b[i][j];
}

Ainv.resize(n);

for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
    Ainv[i].resize(m);

    for(int j = 0; j < Ainv[i].size(); j++)
        Ainv[i][j] = A[i][j];
}


//sets default values for the pivot vector
for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    ipivot[j] = 0;


//main loop over the inverse dimensions for column reductions
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ainvabs = 0.0;

    //search for pivot elements
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(ipivot[j] != 1)
        {
            for(k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                if(ipivot[k] == 0)
                {
                    if(fabs(Ainv[j][k]) >= ainvabs)
                    {
                        ainvabs = fabs(Ainv[j][k]);

                        irow = j;

                        icolumn = k;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //pivots determined, swap columns with rows (relabeling on columns/rows of matrix)

    ++(ipivot[icolumn]);

    if(irow != icolumn)
    {
        for(l = 0; l < n; l++)
        {
            int temp1 = Ainv[irow][l];
            int temp2 = Ainv[icolumn][l];

            Ainv[irow][l] = temp2;
            Ainv[icolumn][l] = temp1;
        }
        for(l = 0; l < m; l++)
        {
            int temp1 = x[irow][l];
            int temp2 = x[icolumn][l];

            x[irow][l] = temp2;
            x[icolumn][l] = temp1;
        }
    }

    indxr[i] = irow;

    indxc[i] = icolumn;

    if(Ainv[icolumn][icolumn] != 0.0)
        pivinv = 1 / Ainv[icolumn][icolumn];

    for(l = 0; l < n; l++)
        Ainv[icolumn][l] *= pivinv;

    for(l = 0; l < m; l++)
        x[icolumn][l] *= pivinv;

    for(ll = 0; ll < n; ll++)
    {
        if(ll !=icolumn)
        {
            dum = Ainv[ll][icolumn];

            Ainv[ll][icolumn] = 0.0;

            for(l = 0; l < n; l++)
                Ainv[ll][l] -= Ainv[icolumn][l] * dum;

            for(l = 0; l < m; l++)
                x[ll][l] -= x[icolumn][l] * dum;
        }
    }

    //reductions complete, interchange elements in reverse order as before

    for(l = n - 1; l >= 0; l--)
    {
        if(indxr[l] != indxc[l])
        {
            for(k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                int temp1 = Ainv[k][indxr[l]];
                int temp2 = Ainv[k][indxc[l]];

                Ainv[k][indxr[l]] = temp2;
                Ainv[k][indxc[l]] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

These are the messages i get when using valgrind. They are very messy, please let me know if it would be easier to shorten these a bit, I don't really know which parts are useful vs parts that aren't so I've just copied the entire message.

```
==52421== Invalid write of size 8
==52421==    at 0x100021B67:                     

Math::gaussJordanElimination(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double,     std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >) (type_traits:3599)
==52421==    by 0x100025D3D: LearningAlgorithms::KRR(DataStorage*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) (LearningAlgorithms.cpp:171)
==52421==    by 0x100018FAE: Run::trainModel(DataStorage*) (Run.cpp:291)
==52421==    by 0x100000E8A: main (Main.cpp:131)
==52421==  Address 0x1021f62e0 is 240 bytes inside a block of size 312 free'd
==52421==    at 0x10004A32D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:534)
==52421==    by 0x100018E91: Run::trainModel(DataStorage*) (new:176)
==52421==    by 0x100000E8A: main (Main.cpp:131)
==52421==  Block was alloc'd at
==52421==    at 0x100049D81: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==52421==    by 0x1009A27DD: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==52421==    by 0x100006AFF: _ZNSt3__16vectorINS0_IdNS_9allocatorIdEEEENS1_IS3_EEE18__construct_at_endIPS3_EENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeES9_S9_m (memory:1596)
==52421==    by 0x100006A05: std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >::vector(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > > const&) (vector:1203)
==52421==    by 0x100018D8D: Run::trainModel(DataStorage*) (vector:1195)
==52421==    by 0x100000E8A: main (Main.cpp:131)       







==52421== Invalid read of size 8
==52421==    at 0x100021BA5: Math::gaussJordanElimination(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >) (type_traits:3597)
==52421==    by 0x100025D3D: LearningAlgorithms::KRR(DataStorage*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) (LearningAlgorithms.cpp:171)
==52421==    by 0x100018FAE: Run::trainModel(DataStorage*) (Run.cpp:291)
==52421==    by 0x100000E8A: main (Main.cpp:131)
==52421==  Address 0x102e54ec8 is 232 bytes inside a block of size 312 free'd
==52421==    at 0x10004A32D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:534)
==52421==    by 0x100018E91: Run::trainModel(DataStorage*) (new:176)
==52421==    by 0x100000E8A: main (Main.cpp:131)
==52421==  Block was alloc'd at
==52421==    at 0x100049D81: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==52421==    by 0x1009A27DD: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==52421==    by 0x100006AFF: _ZNSt3__16vectorINS0_IdNS_9allocatorIdEEEENS1_IS3_EEE18__construct_at_endIPS3_EENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeES9_S9_m (memory:1596)
==52421==    by 0x100006A05: std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >::vector(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > > const&) (vector:1203)
==52421==    by 0x100018D8D: Run::trainModel(DataStorage*) (vector:1195)
==52421==    by 0x100000E8A: main (Main.cpp:131)






valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:303 (SizeT get_bszB_as_is(Block *)): Assertion     'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 80, hi = 195611105019399384.

This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.   






host stacktrace:
==52421==    at 0x2380501B3: ???
==52421==    by 0x2380505CC: ???
==52421==    by 0x2380505AA: ???
==52421==    by 0x23805E6F8: ???
==52421==    by 0x238040389: ???
==52421==    by 0x23803F316: ???
==52421==    by 0x238046D47: ???
==52421==    by 0x23803E613: ???
==52421==    by 0x238006E47: ???
==52421==    by 0x7000012B7851: ???
==52421==    by 0x700000DB1EEF: ???
==52421==    by 0x700000DB1EEF: ???
==52421==    by 0x700000009C9F: ???
==52421==    by 0x700000009CAF: ???

sched status:
  running_tid=1







Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 2567)
==52421==    at 0x100021BA9: Math::gaussJordanElimination(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >) (type_traits:3598)
==52421==    by 0x100025D3D: LearningAlgorithms::KRR(DataStorage*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) (LearningAlgorithms.cpp:171)
==52421==    by 0x100018FAE: Run::trainModel(DataStorage*) (Run.cpp:291)
==52421==    by 0x100000E8A: main (Main.cpp:131)
```

Comment: What did you observe when inspecting your code with the debugger line by line?

Comment: There is a very simple reason "why this error is occuring": there is a bug somewhere in your code. Unfortunately, without a [mcve], no authoritative answer will be possible. This bug can be anywhere. A unique feature of C++ is that a bug that results in memory corruption will not necessarily result in an immediate crash. The crash can occur at any point later, when another part of the code chokes on the corrupted memory. Therefore, without a [mcve], no authoritative answer is possible, and it's unlikely why anyone would want to thrift through this massive pile of code, looking for one.

Comment: Can you copy this code to an online compiler such as Ideone.com or Cpp.sh, make it actually compile (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example) and share a link?

Comment: *The issue I'm having is that, upon completion of this function the program crashes with this error:* -- My advice:  start using `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` to ensure that you are not going out-of-bounds.  If you are going out of bounds, then an `out_of_range` exception will be thrown.  Also, you need to really be careful with your tests: `int n = A.size(); int m = A[0].size();` -- what if `A` is empty?

Comment: You are correct about using .at() vs [], however in the case of A[0].size() I am assuring that A is not empty before the raw data gets passed into the KRR function. But i appreciate the comment, and it probably is better practice overall.  I also understand that it is difficult to find an error in this mess of code, however, due to the complexity of the program, and everything else that happens before this function is even called, it would be extremely difficult to reduce the program to a single example that focuses on just the KRR function.

Comment: I also wanted to say that the reason i am indexing the vectors as vector[i] rather than vector.at(i) is because this program is very time-dependent, and the amount of data stored in the vectors reaches millions of elements, and by indexing it this way I am reducing the computational time by nearly half.

Comment: @JamesChapman How fast it takes doesn't matter if it crashes :-) Also, don't be too fixated on the KRR function: as Sam Varshavchik explained, where the original error occurs (where the invalid memory access occurs, corrupting the memory blocks) could be far-removed from where the error is detected.

Comment: @JamesChapman -  *I also wanted to say that the reason i am indexing the vectors as vector[i] rather than vector.at(i) is because this program is very time-dependent*  -- Is your debugging time also important?  Temporarily add in `at()` statements to see if any one of them triggers an exception being thrown.  If you find such an error, then you found at least one issue and fix that issue.  What good is speed if the program is crashing?  All you would be  doing is temporarily changing the code to detect such crashes.  Also, never assume anything -- your code should check for empty.

Answer (score 0):

So after 5 days of pulling my hair out over this i finally figured it out.

In the Guass-Jordan Elimination function:

```
int m = A[0].size()
```

should be...

```
int m = b[0].size()
```

as m determines the columns of x, and matrix multiplication wouldn't work if x was the same size as A and the dimensions of b were not the same as A.

There are probably more errors in this code, but this issue is the direct cause of the program crashing.

Comment: And as my main comment(s) to you stated, if you would have placed `at()` statements temporarily within your code, you would have found the issue within minutes, not days.